# Difference in combineLatest behaviour Signal v SignalProducer (ReactiveCocoa 4)

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa-4

I'm running through basic operators at the moment and ran into a difference in the behaviour of the combineLatest operator. I'm not sure if this is a bug or my failure to understand the variation between Signals and SignalProducers.

```
let (numbersSig, numbersOb) = Signal<Int, NoError>.pipe()
let (lettersSig, lettersOb) = Signal<String, NoError>.pipe()
let signal = combineLatest(numbersSig, lettersSig)
signal.observeNext({value in print(value)})

numbersOb.sendNext(1)
lettersOb.sendNext("A")
lettersOb.sendNext("B")
```

Produces:
(1, "A")
(1, "B")

But, if I write what I would consider to be equivalent code using SignalProducers:

```
let numberProducer = SignalProducer<Int, NoError> { (observer, disposable) in
    for v in [1] { observer.sendNext(v) }
}

let letterProducer = SignalProducer<String, NoError> { (observer, disposable) in
    for v in ["A", "B", "C", "D"] { observer.sendNext(v) }
}

let combinedProducer = combineLatest(numberProducer, letterProducer)
combinedProducer.on(next: {value in print(value) }).start()
```

Output:
(1, "D")

I've deliberately left the observer.sendCompleted() out of the SignalProducers as I thought that this would be responsible but that isn't the case. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this does seem like a bug. Would you mind opening an issue on the Github repo so that we can take a look there? Better yet, it would be awesome if you could open a PR with the failing test! :)

I'd check something that might be a workaround: do you get the same result if you use `startWithNext` instead of `on` + `start`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion NachoSoto. I tried the alternate approach you suggested and the output was unchanged. When I posted this issue on the Github repo I received the answer below from aromas (Brian Thomas):

> Calling start on the combinedProducer handles calling start on the
>   internal letter and number producers (Specifically see liftRight in
>   SignalProducer.swift, where when otherProducer.startWithSignal's
>   closure returns it will run your sendNext code). Because they are
>   synchronous the letter producer is simply 'nexting' all of its values
>   before the number producer starts returning values. You can test this
>   by reversing them in the combineLatest method call in the producer
>   example. If you want to get the 'push values' behavior of your first
>   test try
>
> ```
> let (numbersSig, numbersSink) = Signal<Int, NSError>.pipe()
> let (lettersSig, lettersSink) = Signal<String, NSError>.pipe()
> let numberProducer = SignalProducer(signal: numbersSig)
> let letterProducer = SignalProducer(signal: lettersSig)
>
> let combinedProducer = combineLatest(numberProducer, letterProducer)
> combinedProducer.on(next: {value in print(value) }).start()
>
> lettersSink.sendNext("A")
> numbersSink.sendNext(1)
> lettersSink.sendNext("B")
> numbersSink.sendNext(2)
> lettersSink.sendNext("C")
> ```

I tried reversing numberProducer and letterProducer as he suggested and the output was indeed as I originally encountered using Signals i.e.

```
let numberProducer = SignalProducer<Int, NoError> { (observer, disposable) in
    for v in [1] { observer.sendNext(v) }
}

let letterProducer = SignalProducer<String, NoError> { (observer, disposable) in
    for v in ["A", "B", "C", "D"] { observer.sendNext(v) }
}

let combinedProducer = combineLatest(letterProducer, numberProducer)
combinedProducer.startWithNext {value in print(value)}
```

Produces: 
("A", 1)
("B", 1)
("C", 1)
("D", 1)

Do you still think this is a bug or an implementation behaviour?